# Cross Join across intermediary tables

Tags: postgresql, cross-join

I have a database with 3 tables: Cohort time periods, users and events.

Cohorts have many users, each user has many events. Cohorts also have periods of time associated with them. I'd like to know for each cohort, for each period of time how many events occurred.

If there were 2 tables it would be easy to do a `CROSS JOIN` but I'm stuck when there's this intermediary table.

Here's the DB structure:

```
create table time_periods (
  cohort_name varchar,
  period_name varchar,
  start_time timestamp,
  end_time timestamp);

create table users (
  cohort_name varchar,
  user_name varchar
);

create table events (
  user_name varchar,
  ts timestamp);

insert into time_periods values
('cohort1', 'first', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-10'),
('cohort1', 'second', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-20'),
('cohort2', 'first', '2017-01-15', '2017-01-20');

insert into users values
  ('cohort1', 'alice'),
  ('cohort2', 'bob');

insert into events values 
('alice', '2017-01-07'),
('alice', '2017-01-17'),
('bob', '2017-01-18');
```

This is as far as I can get with the SQL - doing a triple cross join but it is not correct - the result is 6 events, when it should be just 1 per row.

```
select
  time_periods.cohort_name,
  period_name,
  count(ts)
from time_periods, users, events
group by 1, 2
order by time_periods.cohort_name
```

Here's the SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b141e/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify on which columns you want to join the tables
If I understand your data correctly you want something like this:

```
select
  tp.cohort_name,
  tp.period_name,
  count(*)
from time_periods tp
inner join users u on tp.cohort_name = u.cohort_name 
inner join events e on u.user_name = e.user_name and e.ts between tp.start_time and tp.end_time
group by 1, 2
order by tp.cohort_name
```

In here you join from `time_periods` to `users` only for users in correct cohort and then join to `events` only for specified users and events in particular time period, then grouping by 1 and 2 to get the correct even count

Comment: Ah! I've never seen that `between` syntax. That's what I was looking for! I was trying to solve it with a CASE WHEN + SUM but it wasn't working. Thanks :)

Comment: aww, that sounds complicated... sql is not half bad with dates and between is just a syntactic sugar for < x <.